# VLCJ calculate dropped frames from remote video

Tags: frame-rate, vlcj

I am currently working on a video to video application, which uses the VLCJ api 2.2.0 for the media streaming. 
What I want to do is calculate the dropped frames of the remote video stream. Specifically, i have set an upper limit of maximum FPS, and thus  the calculation should be :
lostFPS = maximumFPS - currentFPS.

I saw in the javadoc of vlcj that the currentFPS is provided by the getFPS function, but it always returns 0 for some reason even if the video is streamed normally (both for local and remote).

Does anyone know if there are alternative ways of calculating this loss or am i missing something?

Best regards,
giannis

Answer (score 0):

libVLC provides statistics about the currently playing media, vlcj exposes it:

```
libvlc_media_stats_t stats = mediaPlayer.getMediaStatistics();
int droppedFrames = stats.i_lost_pictures;
```